# How are the (syntactic) differences in these two definitions of the characteristic polynomial of a square matrix explained?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

I’m used to defining the characteristic polynomial of a square matrix as follows:
$$p_A(x) = det(xI_n - A)$$
where $A$ is a square matrix over a field and $I$ is an $n \times n$ identity matrix.
The [English Wikipedia entry for the characterstic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) is one example that uses this definition, other examples are [this post on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907289/definition-of-characteristic-polynomial), or [ncatlab.org](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/characteristic+polynomial).

However, there’s some cases (eg. [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicPolynomial.html); various online proofs from [efgh](http://www.efgh.com/math/cayleyhamilton.htm), [planetmath](http://planetmath.org/lecturenotesonthecayleyhamiltontheorem), [Colorado State University](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~yzhou/course/math561_spring2011/CHthm.pdf)) where the definition is:
$$p_A(x) = det(A - xI_n)$$

I tried to find a proof for the equality of the two definitions but didn’t find a solution yet. How do you explain the use of those two (at least syntactically) different definitions of the characteristic polynomial?

(This question is relevant for my research work on formalized proofs of the Cayley-Hamilton-Theoreom and not homework.)

Comment: The roots of those polynomials are the same and this is what matters. Personally I prefer the one you use because it yields a monic polynomial.

Comment: To add a little - from purely "quality of life" point of view -  when we write $\det(A-xI)$ students make fewer mistakes in finding the polynomial by hand (less matrix elements to rewrite with the minus sign, apparently).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a  sign :

$\begin{vmatrix}A-B\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}-(B-A)\end{vmatrix}=(-1)^n\begin{vmatrix}A-B\end{vmatrix}$

If we're just interested in the roots of the polynomial that $(-1)^n$ doesn't really matter.